# How to diagnose that a user is online or offline in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, offline

How can I diagnose someone( a user) is offline or online in asp.net.
For example in web application in asp.net when two people are chatting together if one of them is offline system can diagnose it and be able to show that user is offline.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag column in the user table.. set it as '1' whenever a user logs in, and set it as zero whenever he logs out. So u can track whether the user is in offline or online..